# Why do I still get the move bar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a question and I hope one you guys/girls could help me out. I have created a custom wordpress theme where I keep getting a scroll/movebar to the left and right side of the screen. I have tried to fix it but I couldn't find the solution, I did give my container a max-width from 1280px but it is still more than 1280px. The website has to be 1280px max without a scrollbar to the left and right.

[The link to the website](http://fifaball.nl/)

I really appreciate it if someone could help me out, I already asked some class mates who thought they could me help me out but we still couldn't fix it... I hope one of you guys/girls could help me out because I'm lost at this moment.

Comment: your div#wrapper is 1903px wide....

Comment: The issue is because you have set a fixed width to most of yours divs. Try setting max-width instead.

Comment: once you've fixed the widths (probably using %'s instead of px), then you could use overflow-x:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Your #header, #container, #background and #contact elements have a set width of 1280px, and your #footer element, of 1240px. If the screen resolution is wider than that, no horizontal scroll bars will show. Here's a screenshot taken with a resolution of 1920px wide:

[image]